# Drawing altered by screen mode (portrait or landscape)

Tags: android, drawing, landscape, portrait

I'm porting a game from JME to Android and I found an annoying problem. The next activity must draw a grid, and in fact it does. But the grid appear OK just in landscaping mode. When you put the phone vertical (in portrait mode) it appears strangely compressed.
The main code is the method used to draw a cells row, (getSquareRow)
Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class TraxActivity extends Activity {
    InternalView myView;
    private float shift, di;
    private float n, minim, redux, side;
    boolean first = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myView = new InternalView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }

    private class InternalView extends View{
        public InternalView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            n=5;
            di=12;
            int ancho = getWidth();
            int alto = getHeight();
            minim = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
            redux = minim*9/10;
            shift = (getWidth() - redux)/2;
            side = redux/n;

            //background
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);

            //grid
            for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
                getSquareRow( canvas, j, paint);
            } 



        }




        public void getSquareRow(Canvas g, int row, Paint p){

            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            p.setStrokeWidth(10);

            for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
                g.drawRect(shift+i*side, shift+row*side, side, side, p );
            }

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: I think game should be made in Lanscape mode for better look. So, you can change it to Landscape mode.

Comment: I disagree, yeah some games are locked in landscape. But if you could play your game in both orientations, it is a feature. And technically possible, "better look" can be archieved in both. At least consider supporting rotation against work/time/.. effort. Don't follow the "games must be landscape" reflex blind. In general, supporting two orientations is always better than one. Because the user has a choice what he likes more, resulting in more happy users after all. And happy users engage with your app more or buy other apps from you.

Comment: Yes as @suri said you must go for landscape mode only.You can go for portrait mode too But you must do a lot of changes in graphics if you will go for it because you must set all layouts size according to both mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I'll be targeting the game just for landascaping mode. Althought  I agree with alextsc but in this case looks like Android platform doesn't redraw accurately in portrait mode.
I can't to publish an image because I'm newbie posting here, but running this code you can check the anomaly and seems be related with the method drawRect.